# Create a List compose by matching fields between a List of Maps and an List of Objects using Lambda Functions?

Tags: java, performance, lambda, java-8, refactoring

I'm new to Java lambda expressions and have been struggling with the following problem:

I have a List of label objects, whose fieldsid are the only keys I wanna extract from the other List of Maps.

```
[
    {
        "objectid": 10,
        "eventsourceid": 6,
        "fieldid": "ACQUIRE"
    },
    {
        "objectid": 13,
        "eventsourceid": 6,
        "fieldid": "HASSVALIM"
    }
]
```

The list of Maps has the following structure

```
[
    {
        "ACQUIRE": "1.42541559",
        "PERMCONVERGENT": "CaSPC3",
        "PVP": 133.88,
        "HASSVALIM": "67A4",
        "LASTUPDATE": "2018-10-10T13:38:11.000Z"            
    },
    {
        "ACQUIRE": "2.1327",
        "PERMCONVERGENT": "Calp3",
        "PVP": 23.18,
        "HASSVALIM": "1A24",
        "LASTUPDATE": "2018-10-10T13:38:11.000Z"            
    },
    {
        "ACQUIRE": "1.12459",
        "PERMCONVERGENT": "CaSPC3",
        "PVP": 33.58,
        "HASSVALIM": "653",
        "LASTUPDATE": "2018-10-10T13:38:11.000Z"            
    },
]
```

I want to extract from the List of Maps only the values required in the first List (**fieldid**) and generate a List to generate later an CSV, so the appeareance of my desired List would be:

```
{
    [1.42541559, 67A4],
    [2.1327, 1A24],
    [1.12459, 653],

}
```

*I got the desired result iterating the following way.*

```
    List<Map<String, Object>> dataMapList = this.getTableMap();
    List<CatalogLabel> columnsLabel = this.getCatalogtypelabel(objectid);

    List<String[]> body = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Map<String,Object> map:dataMapList) {
        String[] row = new String[columnsLabel.size()];
        int index=0;
        for(CatalogLabel label:columnsLabel) {
            if(map.containsKey(label.getFieldid())) {
                row[index++] = map.get(label.getFieldid()).toString();
            }
        }
        body.add(row);
    }
```

I wonder if its possible to get a different result using Lambda expressions (stream, filter, collect, map, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible approach with a `Stream` might be

```
final List<List<String>> collect =
    dataMapList.stream()
               .map(map ->
                    columnsLabel.stream()
                                .map(cl -> cl.getFieldid())
                                .map(id -> String.valueOf(map.get(id)))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())
               ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Which outputs

```
[
  [1.42541559, 67A4], 
  [2.1327, 1A24],
  [1.12459, 653]
]
```

Which matches your iterating approach and which avoid working with primitive Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This is the equivalent using streams:

```
List<String[]> body = dataMapList.stream()
        .map(d -> columnsLabel.stream()
                .map(CatalogLabel::getFieldid)
                .map(d::get)
                .map(Object::toString)
                .toArray(String[]::new))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```